# Присвоить переменной значение функции

Tags: c, функции, переменные

Нужно перевести два числа в другую СС, и работать дальше с полученными значениями. Код работает только при типе void, но значения не присваиваются, что добавить?

```
void Preobraz(int a, int p) 
{
        if (a == 0) return;
        Preobraz(a / p, p);
        printf("%d", a % p);
}


int main()
{
    int n, m, p, nnov, mnov;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    printf("Введите первое число n=");
    scanf_s("%d", &n);
    printf("Введите второе число m=");
    scanf_s("%d", &m);
    printf("Введите основание новой системы счисления от 2 до 9 p=");
    scanf_s("%d", &p);
    while (p < 2 || p > 9)
    {
        printf("Введите заново (значение некорректно) p=");
        scanf_s("%d", &p);
    }

    Preobraz(n, p);
    Preobraz(m, p);
}
```

Comment: У вас нет условия выхода их рекурсии в функции Preobraz, и она ничего не возвращает

Comment: ...и даже не выводит на экран. Разве что сообщение о переполнении стека.

Comment: А зачем вообще тут рекурсия? Можно же просто циклом. И кстати, цифры числа при делении на основание будут получаться в обратном порядке. Т.е., даже если вы перепишите корректно свой Preobraz(), числа будут выводиться задом на перёд.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int Preobraz(int a, int p)
{
        if (a < p) return a;
        return a % p+10*Preobraz(a / p, p);
}


int main()
{
    system("chcp 1251");
    int n, m, p, nnov, mnov;
    printf("Введите первое число n=");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Введите второе число m=");
    scanf("%d", &m);
    printf("Введите основание новой системы счисления от 2 до 9 p=");
    scanf("%d", &p);
    while (p < 2 || p > 9)
    {
        printf("Введите заново (значение некорректно) p=");
        scanf("%d", &p);
    }

    nnov = Preobraz(n, p);
    mnov = Preobraz(m, p);
    printf ("Числа %d и %d получились\n", nnov, mnov);
}
```

Только у меня по-другому настроен вывод текста на русском. И для больших чисел будут проблемы в общем-то, так как они за пределы выйдут.

Comment: ОК, но что, если количество десятичных цифр в преобразованном числе станет больше 10 (а именно столько влазит в тип int)? И снова знак не учтён (числа могут же быть и отрицательными). Но смотрится красиво))

Comment: P.S. По-этому зачастую и приходится "усложнять" код, чтобы он работал всегда и везде

Answer (score 1):

Я смотрю, вы исправили код. И всё равно он страдает от изъянов. Во-первых, не выводит 0; во-вторых, не учитывает знак числа; (в-третьих, не выводит '\n' в конце).

Далее. Целесообразнее написать отдельную функцию, которая преобразует число в строку с заданным основанием - это более универсальный подход, чем прямой вывод цифр в консоль.

В общем, если учесть замечания выше, то код получается несколько интереснее. Предлагаю ознакомиться (ваш стиль я постарался максимально сохранить):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <locale.h>

#define NUM_CHARS 34    //максимальная длина строки с двоичным числом + 2 (знак и конечный ноль)

void num_to_str(int num, int base, char pszDstBuf[NUM_CHARS])
{
    assert ((base>=2)&&(base<=10));  //дополнительная проверка не помешает

    bool bNeg = false;
    char* pChr = pszDstBuf + NUM_CHARS - 1;

    *pChr = '\0';

    //учитываем знак
    if (num < 0)
    {
        bNeg = true;
        if (num!=0x80000000) num = -num;
        else
        {
            //число 0x80000000 (-2147483648) при инверсии не меняет знака - это особый случай
            *(--pChr) = (-(num%base))|0x30;
            num = -(num/base);
        }
    }

    //выполняем преобразование
    if (num)
    {
        do
        {
            *(--pChr) = (num%base)|0x30;    //к сырой цифре добавляем 0x30 - получаем ASCII-символ этой цифры
            num/= base;
        } while (num);

        if (bNeg) *(--pChr) = '-';
    }
    else *(--pChr) = '0';

    //сдвигаем строку в начало буфера
    if (pChr > pszDstBuf)
    {
        char chr;

        do
        {
            chr = *(pChr++);
            *(pszDstBuf++) = chr;
        } while (chr!='\0');
    }
}


void Preobraz(int a, int p) 
{
    char szBuf[NUM_CHARS];

    num_to_str(a,p,szBuf);
    printf("%s\n", szBuf);
}


int main()
{
    int n, m, p;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    printf("Введите первое число n=");
    scanf_s("%d", &n);
    printf("Введите второе число m=");
    scanf_s("%d", &m);
    printf("Введите основание новой системы счисления от 2 до 9 p=");
    scanf_s("%d", &p);
    while (p < 2 || p > 9)
    {
        printf("Введите заново (значение некорректно) p=");
        scanf_s("%d", &p);
    }
    Preobraz(n, p);
    Preobraz(m, p);
}
```

Comment: Очень сложный код какой-то.

Comment: @xmikex вполне нормальный рабочий код, в котором учтены все особености алгоритма (основные моменты я даже закомментил). Сложным он только кажется. Вы ещё опенсорсовых исходников не видели)))